# c# ext.net: Cannot get items of fieldset added dynamically

Tags: c#, code-behind, ext.net, fieldset

I add some `numberfields` dynamically to a `fieldset` in a `Direct Method` like this:

```
var visits = from v in dc.Visits
                     where v.tid == tid
                     select v;

        foreach (var v in visits)
        {
            NumberField nf = new NumberField();
            nf.ID = v.VISITName + "num";
            nf.MaxValue = 100;
            nf.MinValue = 0;
            nf.FieldLabel = v.VISITName;
            PerVisitFS.Items.Add(nf);
            nf.Render();
        }
```

But later when I am trying to get the values of these fields that the user entered I get `PerVisitFS.Items.Count() = 0`.

How I can get those values?

Comment: Are you sure visits has data?

Comment: @BugFinder yes. checked with breakpoints

Comment: When you trace it through it itterates through the adding to PerVisitFS? and at that point you see content?

Comment: @BugFinder yes. But when I try to iterate the second time to get the values then its empty

Comment: Then somewhere else you empty / remake it